# writing completefunc in python

Tags: python, vim

So, I'm attempting to implement a custom `completefunc` in python, but I'm having trouble getting the code to interface correctly. I'm after it providing me with (initially) a list of filenames from a fixed directory (This will get replaced with a different list shortly).

My latest attempt looks like this:

```
function! CompleteNVIM(findstart,base)
python <<
import vim
import os

def complete( base ):
   matches = [ "'"+os.path.splitext(x)[0]+"'" for x in os.listdir('notes') ]
   vim.command( "let p = [" + ",".join(matches) + "]" )
   return vim.eval('p')

def findstart():
   r,c = vim.current.window.cursor
   l = vim.current.line
   while c>0 and l[c-1] != '[':
      c=c-1
   return c

def complete_nvim( findstart,base ):
  if 1==findstart:
    return findstart()
  else:
    return complete( base )
.

return python complete_nvim(a:findstart,a:base)

endfunction

set completefunc=CompleteNVIM
```

However, the return complains about `no variable named python`. If I omit the `python`, I get an `unknown function complete_nvim` error.

I've tried this for the ending as well:

```
if 1==findstart:
  return findstart()
else:
  return complete( base )
.

endfunction
```

(i.e. removing the `def complete_nvim chunk`, but that fails as I'm then trying to return from outside a function (or so python thinks).

I've also tried putting the python functions in an initialisation function and then trying `set completefunc=complete_nvim`, but that also fails with unknown function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging through some plugins, I've reached the conclusion that python functions in vim cannot directly return a value.

The work around is to use globals, like this:

```
def complete( base ):
   matches = [ "'"+os.path.splitext(x)[0]+"'" for x in os.listdir('notes') ]
   vim.command( "let g:result = [" + ",".join(matches) + "]" )


...

let g:result = []
python complete_nvim(vim.eval('a:findstart'),vim.eval('a:base'))
return g:result
```

Note also the need to use `vim.eval` when passing the arguments